# How to update a field in two identical column

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm new to Oracle. I have created a below table

```
SQL> select * from t12;

  COL1      COL2                 COL3
---------- -------------------- ---------
     5      Social               15-OCT-90
     7      Chemistry            17-OCT-90
     7      Chemistry            17-OCT-90
```

2nd and 3rd row are identical. how can i update only 3rd row,col1 on this table?

Comment: Add a unique primary key

Comment: Primary key is unique by itself. You could say unique key or primary key, unique primary key makes no real sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the concept of "second" or "third" row is a bit nebulous in this case, but you might try something like:

```
update t12
set col1=8
where rowid=(select min(rowid) from t12 where col1=7);
```